# Devise methods in helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a helper module ModelHelper. I want to use user_signed_in? method inside that helper module. But it shows error. How can I call this method inside helper file.

Comment: Please include the code in question and a stack trace that shows the actual error. "But it shows error." - is really just useless information. And you're really just making us make hypothetical guesses about what is wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `user_signed_in?` defined in the `Devise::Controllers::Helpers::ClassModule` module. Long story short it just checks if `scope` authenticated in `warden`. So you can try to check it without `Devise` helpers

```rb
def #{mapping}_signed_in?
  !!current_#{mapping}
end

def current_#{mapping}
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use `current_user.present?`
Anyway, rails helpers are very ugly and I advise to don't use it at all